# First-in-first-out (FIFO) inventory costing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here's an interesting article that I found useful on my project:

[Set-based Speed Phreakery: The FIFO Stock Inventory SQL Problem](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/):

> Stock table which we use to track the track movements of stock in and out of our imaginary stock warehouse. Our warehouse is initially empty, and stock then moves into the warehouse as a result of a stock purchase (tranCode = 'IN'), or due to a subsequent return (tranCode = 'RET'), and stock moves out of the warehouse when it is sold (tranCode = 'OUT'). Each type of stock tem is indentified by an ArticleID. Each movement of stock in or out of the warehouse, due to a purchase, sale or return of a given item, results in a row being added to the Stock table, uniquely identified by the value in the StockID identity column, and describing how many items were added or removed, the price for purchases, the date of the transaction, and so on.

Though I'm using this on my on-going project, Im stuck on how to get the price-to-charge on every transaction 'OUT'. I need to have this value to determine how much i will charge my customers.

1. First add 5 apples (each $10.00) to the stock, for a total of $50.00
2. Add 3 apples (each $20.00) to the stock total of 8 apples, for a total price of $110.00
3. Then take out 6 items (5 each $10.00 and 1 each $20.00)  $70 total
4. After the transaction it will be leaving 2 apples @$20 each with a total of $40

---

```
 Here's my current table
 Item    transaction code    qty     price   
 apple   IN                    5     10.00    
 apple   IN                    3     20.00   
 apple   OUT                   6          

 Manual computation for the OUT transaction price (FIFO)
 QTY     price   total price 
 5       10.00   50.00 
 1       20.00   20.00 
 TOTAL:6         70.00 

 Output of the script:
 Item    CurrentItems   CurrentValue
 apple   2            40.00

 What I need:
 Item    transaction code    qty     price   CurrentItems    CurrentValue 
 apple   IN                    5     10.00   5               50.00 
 apple   IN                    3     20.00   8               110.00 
 apple   OUT                   6             2                   40.00 

 This too will be OK
 Item    transaction code    qty     price   CurrentItems    
 apple   IN                    5     10.00   0               
 apple   IN                    3     20.00   0                
 apple   OUT                   6         70
```

The script posted that won the competition was very useful, I hope someone can help me on how to get the price per 'OUT' transaction

Comment: you need to give every transaction (In, Out, ret)a unique number so that you can know qty and price of the apples. Based on that you can calculate how much total has been by calculating ( qty * price )

Comment: There's a primary key in the stock table. its just that i didnt want to show it for simplicity, I'm also using ItemID instead of the word apple. You can't just calculate the price by (qty*price) alone, remember I need to implement the FIFO rule.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to design your table as below:
Add a new field to your table, i.e. qty_out

The table before selling:

```
Item transaction code    qty     qty_out  price   
 apple   IN                    5    0        10.00    
 apple   IN                    3    0        20.00   
 apple   OUT                   6    null
```

And the table after selling the 6 items:

```
Item    transaction code    qty     qty_out  price   
 apple   IN                    5    5        10.00    
 apple   IN                    3    1        20.00   
 apple   OUT                   6    null
```

You can compare "qty" with "qty_out" (for IN transactions) to find out the price.

Answer (score 0):

How about constructing a table which has a row per product item, so a row for each apple is inserted along with it's price and availability (unsold/sold). 
Then you can just select the top n items, with the price associated with each of the products you want. Essentially you're just creating a queue of items and removing the ones that are "unsold" from the front (with the oldest insert date) of the queue.

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what my table is doing. maybe I didnt get your point, can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article, the result that script got was the value of the inventory. You would need to modify this so that instead of calculating for all of the inventory, you only use the first N items.

I would suggest a CASE statement to set the number of items from each 'IN' as you check against the running total since you know the inventory items and the number you want to take out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot track each OUT transaction itself, but you can calculate it by taking last (except for which you gonna calculate) IN or OUT row and it's current value column and minus current value for which you want to calculate.

in this example

```
StockID  ArticleID  TranDate  TranCode  Items    Price    CurrentItems  CurrentValue
4567     10000      10:45:07  IN          738   245.94             738    181,503.72
21628    10000      12:05:25  OUT         600                      138     33,939.72
22571    10000      14:39:27  IN           62   199.95             200     46,336.62
30263    10000      16:14:13  OUT         165                       35      6,998.25
42090    10000      18:18:58  RET           5                       40      7,998.00
53143    10000      20:18:54  IN          500   135.91             540     75,953.00
```

for transaction 30263 price will be 46,336.62 - 6,998.25 = **39,338.37**

Answer (score 0):

See the code below in TSQL. The basic idea is

1. for each sell row, say the quantity is Qty, calculate running total sales PRIOR to the current row, call it Previous_Sold.
2. for each sell row in step 1, find all PREVIOUS buy rows and calculate running total stock UP TO that buy, call it Previous_Running_Stock.
3. for buy rows in step 2, calculate

Open_Stock = Previous_Running_Stock - Previous_Sold

Close_stock = Previous_Running_Stock - Previous_Sold - Qty.

4. Filter and only keep buy rows if

open_stock >0, meaning there is enough stock to fill the sell order

and close_stock < 0, meaning stock from the buy row all used up, or earliest (first row) where close_stock >= 0, meaning purchase from that row is partially used.

5. aggregate (sum product of) price and quantity to get LIFO cost in step 4.

I believe it can be easily modified to LIFO and average cost too.

```
--initial table of trades
item       item_trade_order     direction  unit_price    qty
Apple      1                    buy        10            100
Apple      2                    buy        9             150
Blueberry  1                    buy        5             300   
Apple      3                    sell       12            50
Apple      4                    buy        11            200
Apple      5                    sell       10            350
Blueberry  2                    sell       10            50


--code, using CTE


; with step1 as
(
    select *
        , coalesce(sum(case direction when 'sell' then 1 else 0 end * qty) over(partition by item order by item_order rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) Previous_Sold
    from trade 
)
, step2_3 as
(
    select *
        , Previous_running_stock - Previous_Sold Open_Stock
        , Previous_running_stock - Previous_Sold - qty Close_Stock
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by item, item_order order by (case when Previous_running_stock - Previous_Sold - qty < 0  then null else 0 - item_order end) desc) rnk
    from step1 t1
    cross apply
    (
        select item_order batch_order, price batch_prc, qty batch_qty
            , sum(qty) over(order by item_order rows unbounded preceding) Previous_running_stock
        from trade
        where direction = 'buy'
        and item = t1.item
        and item_order < t1.item_order
    ) batch
    where t1.direction = 'sell'
)
, step4 as
(
    select *
    from step2_3
    where Open_Stock > 0
    and (Close_Stock < 0 or rnk = 1)
)
select item, item_order, direction, AVG(price) prc, AVG(qty) qty
    ,   sum(case when Close_Stock > 0 then batch_qty - close_stock else case when open_stock < batch_qty then open_stock else batch_qty end end * Batch_Prc) / nullif(avg(qty), 0) FifoUnitCost
from step4
group by item, item_order, direction
order by item, item_order
```