# Need suggestion on how to implement FIFO reporting logic in Teradata

Tags: teradata

[On hand table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2efjC.png)

[Receipt table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zns7R.png)

[Output needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zG6M.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here's a link on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  And please don't use links to images.

Comment: Without checking those pictures there's an old thread on implementing FIFO https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137015/2527905